# Alter output of ServiceStack.Text JSON Deserializer

Tags: c#, .net, json, xamarin, servicestack-text

I'm currently using the `Newtonsoft.json` nuget package but I'd like to find a faster alternative.  `ServiceStack.Text` seems to parse it, but it's returning the JSON in a different format that I'm expecting.  Is there anyway to change the format in which this returns the object to match what I'm expecting?

**The problem is** that after deserializing, `response.fullName` returns "joey cool" as expected for `Newtonsoft.json` but the `ServiceStack.Text` will return a `null` because the format is different.

Can I alter the outputting format of the `ServiceStack.Text` so that it matches what I'm expecting?  I want to call `response.fullName` and get "joey cool".

**Here is my code using the `ServiceStack.Text` component:**

```
T response = a_response.Content.FromJson<T>();
```

**Here is my code using `Newtonsoft.json`:**

```
T response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(a_response.Content);
```

**Below is how the JSON in text looks as output:**

> {
>     "userId": "fc7b4c4e0b6660c7daf711b1d17e0039",
>     "emailAddress": "joey+100@stringify.com",
>     "fullName": "joey cool",
>     "accountType": "individual",
>     "createdDate": 1440104822411,
>     "phoneNumber": "15555555555",
>     "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
>     "photo": "https://stringify.s3.amazonaws.com/users/fc7b4c4e0b6660c7daf711b1d17e0039-profile.jpg",
>     "name": "default",
>     "type": "api"
>   }

**Below is how the debugger shows the `Newtonsoft.json` object:**
[image]

**Below is how your `ServiceStack.Text` JSON Deserializer shows the response object:** 
[image]

----EDIT----
Tried 4.0.62 from NuGet and it gives me an exception.

Message: The type initializer for 'ServiceStack.StringExtensions' threw an exception.  Object reference not set to instance of an object,   at ServiceStack.StringExtensions..cctor () [0x00017] in :0

[image]

-----EDIT-----

[URL to a file containing the JSON class](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vpi3de58a6agvr5/ViewControllerToUpload.cs?dl=0)

[Here's a video demonstrating the usage differences and the strange output](https://youtu.be/Lr5hbuUm5dA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the **latest v4** of ServiceStack.Text [which is now free from v4.0.62+](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2016/v4.0.62.md#servicestacktext-is-now-free) and is [available in all Xamarin platforms](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2016/v4.0.62.md#available-on-most-popular-net-platforms).

It's had a lot of improvements added to it since v3 so if this behavior was a result of a bug in v3, it's likely fixed now.

Edit:

This class you're trying to serialize is invalid, ServiceStack either serializes Dictionaries or POCO classes with public properties, it doesn't do both, e.g:

```
[JsonObject (MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class UserDataDict : Dictionary<string, object>
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string userID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string emailAddress { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string fullName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string accountType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string units { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string unitsDistance { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string newsletterSub { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty (NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string location { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty (NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty (NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string address { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty (NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string photo { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty (NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string createdDate { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty (NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string verifyURL { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty (NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string timezone { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty (NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include)]
    public APIManifestDict apiManifest { get; set; }
}
```

I would remove Inheriting the dictionary since it's much more interoperable to have your class contain a dictionary then inherit from one. Also your `[JsonProperty]` attributes are JSON.NET specific and have no effect in other serializers so I'd rewrite your class to:

```
public class UserData
{
    public string userID { get; set; }
    public string emailAddress { get; set; }
    public string fullName { get; set; }
    public string accountType { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
    public string unitsDistance { get; set; }
    public string newsletterSub { get; set; }

    public string location { get; set; }
    public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string photo { get; set; }
    public string createdDate { get; set; }
    public string verifyURL { get; set; }
    public string timezone { get; set; }
    public APIManifestDict apiManifest { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string,string> Metadata { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to include nulls you can specify it with:

```
JsConfig.IncludeNullValues = true;
```

But I'd recommend against your App relying on the presence of nulls as your properties are naturally null if their not included in the JSON payload. Including nulls is more fragile, have to cater for multiple definitions of emptiness, inhibits versioning and just bloats the payload.

Comment: When I try to use 4.0.62 from NuGet, I get an exception.  Is it a Xamarin issue?  I attached more details of the exception above. 
Message: The type initializer for 'ServiceStack.StringExtensions' threw an exception.  Object Ref not set to instance of an object  at ServiceStack.StringExtensions..cctor () [0x00017] in <filename unknown>:0

Comment: You need to [initialize the client](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile/blob/master/README.md#initializing-pcl-client) if you haven't already

Comment: So I got that working, had to use ServiceStack.Client instead of the default one.  But i'm still having the same problem.  The JSON is showing incorrectly.... It's outputting in the same broken format as the Xamarin component.

Comment: @LampShade Can you post the C# Class definition you're deserializing into and the C# code you're using to deserialize?

Comment: I posted a file containing everything you should need.  Also a video demonstrating it.  I believe they key is in how Newtonsoft uses the [JsonObject (MemberSerialization.OptIn)]  to tell it how to parse the JSON... Haven't gotten the equivalent to work with ServiceStack

Comment: @LampShade Your POCO classes are invalid, they can't both inherit dictionaries and have properties, POCOs should be clean models with public properties. See the rewritten class in my updated answer.